# How do I claim land in Lichcraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm new to Lichcraft, and I just recently started Factions.

I know that to claim land, you need enough power and money, but I have no idea how to claim land once that criteria is met.

I thought it might be similar to Skygrid, and tried using a golden shovel, but that did not work.

I am now at risk of being raided. How do I claim land?

Comment: I'm assuming this is some kind of Minecraft mod?

Comment: what. no. i'm talking about lichcraft. a minecraft server like hypixel or mineplex

Comment: IP Address? Plugin name? Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 4):

**/f claim** to claim a specified area of land

**/f claim auto** to claim land while you are walking around

Note that you can only claim Wilderness / other faction land(If your faction power is stronger then the faction, you can claim their land)

If it is not working, try **/f help** instead to check full Faction plugin's command.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/f claim` in the area that you want to claim. Thats how you claim, on most servers.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the /F help command? Occasionally the proper commands and the shovel are required.